# What is a type of graph that's graphing only 1 type of value on a grid?

Tags: data-visualization, scatterplot

What is a type of graph that's graphing only 1 type of value on a grid?

Like, say, you have an ice cream seller, and you collect all the prices for the ice cream, but you somehow don't have any other data. Just the prices. No information about what price goes to which ice cream...

What is the type of graph where I graph that on a grid, with every price as a dot, and spread out horizontally, with 1 observation per gridline?

Although, that is presuming a small number of observations...

Basically, what would this graph be, without the X-axis?

[image]

Comment: People use the term "grid" in many quite different ways.  Because of that, it's impossible to determine with certainty what graph you are trying to describe.  (I suspect I know, but I can think of many variations depending on how the data are ordered and what coordinate system is used.  For instance, will you plot the prices from smallest to largest, or just in some arbitrary order?)  Could you post an example to illustrate?

Comment: I think you are talking about a dot-chart: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_plot_(statistics)

Comment: @Karolis It might be close to Cleveland's dot charts--but I believe an essential part of a dot chart is that it has labels, too, whereas this one does not.  It doesn't sound at all like Wikipedia's description of a "dot plot", for two reasons: (1) it is graphically different and (2) Wikipedia emphasizes its use for identifying "clusters and gaps," but that is meaningless unless there is some underlying ordering to the data.

Comment: Is "what would this graph be, without the X-axis?" equivalent to "what would this plan be, once turned into a line?" I would say that what you want is something analogous to a timeline: a ruler, a priceline, a 1-dimension map. Each ice cream would be located by its price in this (1d) world.

Comment: @Kanak - Yeah... That seems to work, 'cause I just want the rectangular-ness so it takes up more space, and looks similar to other graphs? Although, I could use the observation number as my X-axis...